How to load babel languages conditionally?
I am writing a class in which I grab language-name as a value to a particular key. After that, my plan is to pass it conditionally to babel's language loading mechanism. If I understand the mechanism correctly from the documentation, the languages having .ldf are to be loaded as package options directly and the ones which don't have an .ldf, but an .ini, are to be loaded with the \babelprovide command. Have a look at the following MWE:
\ProvidesClass{mytmpcls}
\LoadClass{article}
\newif\ifmytmpcls@babelini
\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}
\ekvdefinekeys{mytmpcls}{%
  store             language = {\mytmpcls@language},%
  initial           language = {american},%
  store             rmfont   = {\mytmpcls@rmfont},%
  initial           rmfont   = {KpRoman-Regular.otf},%
  store             sffont   = {\mytmpcls@sffont},%
  initial           sffont   = {KpSans-Regular.otf},%
  store             ttfont   = {\mytmpcls@ttfont},%
  initial           ttfont   = {KpMono-Regular.otf}%
}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{mytmpcls}
\RequirePackage[%
  % \IfFileExists{\en}{% doesn't work
    \mytmpcls@language % works without the conditional
  % }{%
  %   \mytmpcls@babelinitrue
  % }% doesn't work
]{babel}
% \ifmytmpcls@babelini
%   \babelprovide{\mytmpcls@language}
% \fi
\babelfont{rm}{\mytmpcls@rmfont}
\babelfont{sf}{\mytmpcls@sffont}
\babelfont{tt}{\mytmpcls@ttfont}

The class can be tried with the following test-file.
\documentclass{mytmpcls}

\begin{document}
hello

\sffamily

hello

\ttfamily

hello
\end{document}

Note: This is a Unicode-only-class, so PDFLaTeX constraints can be ignored safely.
Uncommenting the commented lines from the .cls file fails. The idea is that users can add other languages using the general babel mechanism, add fonts for them, and the default font-settings (for american language) will be in tact. They can change the main language with the language option and can change rm, sf, tt accordingly.

Use PassOptionsToPackage or LaTeX hooks to to add stuff before Babel and after it. In general though I would recommend against trying to pass settings to Babel from the class rather let them add it themselves .

How should the interface to set different fonts for different languages look like? Also, the problem is that \IfFileExists is not expandable, so you can't use it inside \expanded and expect the correct thing to happen.

shouldn't you pass unrecognised options to article? what's \en?

@yannisl thanks for the suggestion, regarding your advice, I just have a single problem that people have to know about babel first and then its mechanism! It took me a long time to get used to it and still I need to go to the documentation (which is fair, I don't have any complaint, but I have seen some people complaining about it who aren't that interested in LaTeX itself). But regardless, I want to know if there is a place to put the code for review? I want the final code to be reviewed pre-release anyways.

@Skillmon didn't know that, that's why the wrong expectation. Regarding setting up the fonts for extra languages, I am working on something, but it's not yet ready. As a last resort, I don't mind leaving that part up to the user. But yet to make a decision.

@cfr My bad, \en was a temporary command from the old MWE which I forgot to change. It didn't occur to me as it was commented anyways. Secondly, why to pass unrecognised options to the article class? expkv has a mechanism to handle unrecognised options and I don't mind using it for passing the options to article, but why? Why should I accept wrong options at the first place?

because otherwise you must handle them all yourself? they will also be unexpectedly in the list of remaining options. why are you so sure the options must be wrong? wrong for what?

So do I understand correctly that the only reason why you want the language key is because you automatically want to be able to use \babelprovide for those not having an .ldf?

Aside: \babelfont has an optional argument specifying a language list for which these fonts shall be used, so you don't need the language key for that functionality in case you wondered.

@Skillmon but importing the languages will still be required, right?

@Skillmon "So do I understand correctly [...]?" Yes, absolutely correctly

@cfr I will think about this, thanks for pointing out.

There is no place that I know but you can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  Best though addit to github or googledrive or some other place on the net and try asking here on meta or chat.

@yannisl thanks, I will do that.

I still think you're better off without mangling too much with the options and just let the users declare the languages globally.

@Skillmon thanks for warning again. I will think about everything and make an alpha version of the class. Share it as a code-review post. We will all discuss again.

Just a little caveat with relation to testing the existence of an ldf. This certainly works for most languages, but a few won't. For example, hebrew.ldf exists, but it doesn't work with xe/lua. Another example is `thai.ldf'.

@JavierBezos thanks a lot for pointing that out. Is this like this for preserving backward compatibility or are there situations where something like this is required? Why I am asking this is, if this is a finite list, I can still code a conditional and escape these situations by calling them exceptions, but hypothetically, if there are reasons for this incompatibility with TUTeX, maybe because of some real limitations of the two engines, then my mechanism will be a bad choice.

@Niranjan These are, at least: arabic, farsi, hebrew, hindi, japanese (very
likely, I’m not sure), thai (maybe a few more, but they are not many). BTW, I’m revamping the manual and suggestions are most welcome: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/babel.pdf .

I'm not sure whether this is really what you want/need, but the following handles your languages (I renamed the key languages, also I changed the syntax of it, its value should be a key=value list containing the languages and any additional options for each individual language as their keys).
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
\ProvidesClass{\@currname}
\LoadClass{article}
\newif\ifmytmpcls@babelini
\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \mytmpcls@add \tl_put_right:Nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \mytmpcls@eadd \tl_put_right:Ne
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\mytmpcls@inis\@empty
\let\mytmpcls@fonts\@empty
\protected\def\mytmpcls@lang#1{\mytmpcls@lang@{#1}{}}
\protected\def\mytmpcls@lang@#1#2%
  {%
    \def\mytmpcls@tmp{#1}%
    \ekvset{mytmpcls/lang}{#2}%
    \IfFileExists{#1.ldf}%
      {\PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}}%
      {\mytmpcls@add\mytmpcls@inis{\babelprovide{#1}}}%
  }
\ekvdefinekeys{mytmpcls/lang}
  {
     protected code rmfont = \mytmpcls@font{rm}{#1}
    ,protected code sffont = \mytmpcls@font{sf}{#1}
    ,protected code ttfont = \mytmpcls@font{tt}{#1}
  }
\protected\def\mytmpcls@font#1#2%
  {\mytmpcls@eadd\mytmpcls@fonts{\noexpand\babelfont[\mytmpcls@tmp]{#1}{#2}}}

\ekvdefinekeys{mytmpcls}{%
  store             languages = \mytmpcls@langs,
  initial           languages = {american},
  store             rmfont    = {\mytmpcls@rmfont},%
  initial           rmfont    = {KpRoman-Regular.otf},%
  store             sffont    = {\mytmpcls@sffont},%
  initial           sffont    = {KpSans-Regular.otf},%
  store             ttfont    = {\mytmpcls@ttfont},%
  initial           ttfont    = {KpMono-Regular.otf}%
}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{mytmpcls}
\ekvparse\mytmpcls@lang\mytmpcls@lang@{V: \mytmpcls@langs}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\mytmpcls@inis
\babelfont{rm}{\mytmpcls@rmfont}
\babelfont{sf}{\mytmpcls@sffont}
\babelfont{tt}{\mytmpcls@ttfont}
\mytmpcls@fonts
\end{filecontents}

% somehow Germans in this example don't like serifs
\documentclass[languages={ngerman={rmfont=KpSans-Regular.otf},american}]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
hello

\sffamily

hello

\ttfamily

hello
\end{document}


Thanks a lot @Skillmon, I thought of value taking keys as a feature request for you, but couldn't find a real example. Now we have it! :)

@Niranjan what do you mean with "value taking keys"? Most of the key-types defined in expkv-def are value taking keys. Or do you mean keys taking key=value lists? That's straight forward possible, either in the way above by using \ekvparse on their values, or by using smeta with a sub-set.

Sorry, I meant value-taking keys whose values take values. key={value={value}}.

@Niranjan in that case smeta is the goto solution here if the structure is akin keyA={subkeyA={value}} (for instance \ekvdefinekeys{foo/bar}{code baz = do the doings} \ekvdefinekeys{foo}{smeta bar = {foo/bar}{#1}} \ekvset{foo}{bar={baz=val}}), and if the structure is more keyA={valA={subvalA}} then nesting an \ekvparse is the way.

Thanks, I will try this out and ask if there are any doubts.
